# How do I git-revert from the command line?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When I do git revert via TortoiseGit, I get this lovely window :

[image]

However, when I want to do the same from the command line, [the documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) manages to completely confuse me. How do I revert all local uncomitted changes?

Comment: Just a vocabulary note: `revert` is to create a new commit that reverts a previous commit, `reset` is what you want (revert uncommited changes)

Comment: @CharlesB: I know they kept that as a holdover from TortoiseSVN, but man, it seems like kind of irresponsible naming.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To discard all local changes, you do not use revert.  revert is for reverting commits.  Instead, do:

```
$ git reset --hard
```

Of course, if you are like me, 7 microseconds after you enter that command you will remember something that you wish you hadn't just deleted, so you might instead prefer to use:

```
$ git stash save 'Some changes'
```

which discards the changes from the working directory, but makes them retrievable.

Comment: Do note that this discards *all* local changes, so it's not an exact replacement for that dialog with checkboxes. If you want to throw away only some changes, use `git checkout <path>...` as [Marc suggests below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339518/how-do-i-git-revert-from-the-command-line/5339716#5339716)

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you haven't committed yet, you can also:

```
git checkout filename(s)
```

Comment: But still will show the file in git status inside files staged to be commited.

Comment: That should only happen if you've previously "git add" it.  If you just edit a file then check it out, it's back to the original.

Answer (score 2):

Git newbies like me should be aware that `working directory' != pwd`.

It rather means the whole tree.

So I'm thankful for Williams recommendation to use:

```
$ git stash save 'Some changes'
```

which can be undone via the following:

```
$ git stash pop
```